# Why are lengths different when an object is curved?

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the above diagram ad is equal to bc. Likewise, ce should be equal to df (Since angle F and E are at 90 degree). My question is why when calculating length of ce and df using $2\pi r$ they are different?

If I was holding a ruler so it is vertical and then bent it a bit at the bottom. Wouldn't the length be the same?

Comment: Wellcome to MathSE! It would be more helpful for us to provide some more insight about your thoughts! However, as a hint, consider that two runners start at poitns $c$ and $d$ and run with the same velocity. Who will arrive first to their route's end?

Comment: If I was holding a ruler so it is vertical and then bent it a bit at the bottom. Wouldn't the length be the same? Runner who started at c because the distance is less. What I'm not getting is why the distance is less

Comment: It's like the fact that on a track, the inside lane is shorter around the curve. So they lag the starts for different lanes to make it fair.

Comment: Have you tried bending a ruler like that? Isn't it difficult? That's because the material is getting stretched and compressed, because the lengths *are* changing. Maybe try it with something more flexible, like a rubber eraser or a piece of foam.

Comment: Try this; take some thread and try to measure the length of two circular items of different radii. You will realize that you will need a longer piece of thread to measure the one with the biggest radius (assume we have equal arcs on both shapes). Alternatively, consider that what you ahve there are two circles with the same centre, so the one with the largest radius will have a larger circumference.

Comment: Also, imagine the diagram was made even wider, so instead of 40 cm you had 1 cm. Do you still think the distances would be the same?

Comment: Thanks for both of you. That made everything clear

Answer (score 0):

imagine that **df** is a part of a circle, and **ce** is a part of another circle
is the circumference of the first circle equal to the circumference of the second one
or less  ? 
i think it's clear now.

Comment: Could you refer to the ruler example I've just added